# Insert into a junction table where main table has a specific ID

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, relational-database

It's a little hard to explain, I will try my best.I am using MySQL and InnoDB.

When I add the second book with the same name, I can't add its ID to book_who_wrote_it table. The first one's ID gets added. That's the problem.

I have a table called book_who_wrote_it. It contains writer_id and book_id. Let's say I have a book named "Metamorphosis". When I add the second book with the same name, even though they have different ID's in the book_id table, the first book's ID is being added to the book_who_wrote_it.

If there are more than one books with the same name, the book_id in the book_who_wrote_it table gets the first book_id.

Here's my table structure

```
book
book_id (PK & AI)
book_original_name
book_synopsis

writer
writer_id (PK & AI)
writer_name

book_who_wrote_it
book_id (FK from book table)
writer_id (FK from writer table)
```

Here's my code.

```
$add_book_writer_name = $_POST['book_writer_name'];
$add_book_original_name = $_POST['book_original_name'];
$add_book_synopsis = $_POST['book_synopsis'];

$writer_id = "SELECT writer_id FROM writer WHERE writer_name = '$add_book_writer_name'";
$writer_result = $sqli->query($writer_id);
$writer_row = $writer_result->fetch_assoc();
$writer_finish = $writer_row['writer_id'];

$book_id = "SELECT book_id FROM book WHERE book_original_name = '$add_book_original_name' AND book_synopsis = '$add_book_synopsis'";
// I am trying to get book name and synopsis to make sure I get the right book id, 
// but I can't make it work.
$book_result = $sqli->query($book_id);
$book_row = $book_result->fetch_assoc();
$book_finish = $book_row['book_id'];

$stmt = $sqli->prepare("INSERT INTO book(book_original_name, book_synopsis) VALUES(?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $add_book_original_name, $add_book_synopsis);
$stmt->execute();

$who_wrote_it = $sqli->prepare("INSERT INTO book_who_wrote_it(book_id, writer_id) VALUES(?,?)");
$who_wrote_it->bind_param("ii", $book_finish, $writer_finish);
$who_wrote_it->execute();
```

So how can I add the second one's ID to book_who_wrote_it table, even if the two books have the same name?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: When I add the second book with the same name, I can't add its ID to book_who_wrote_it table. The first one's ID gets added.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ - And for your question: As you search for the books name you get only one ID of the book. The database decides which one (when there are more than one) however according to the query it's undefined (you say you get the first ID all the time which is typical for mysql however, even you do so, don't expect it for all eternity).

Comment: The question still remains: What is your question? According to your code this is how it should and must be. If you want to change that, change what `$book_finish` contains. Just put the value in there that is correct.

Comment: All I want to do is to find the book_id that contain the book_original_name and book_synopsis. I added book_synopsis on purpose, because some books can have same names but they always will have different synopsis. @PythonMaster, thank you for your edit. I approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it.

There is nothing wrong with the code except the order of the queries. I was trying to SELECT a record from the database before inserting it, that was the problem.